# Are these Cantor spaces and what numbers does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{4^{n+1}}$ contain?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cantor-set

> Are these Cantor spaces and what numbers does 
>   $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{4^{n+1}}$ contain?

The Cantor set in the real numbers can be defined as the set of infinite sums:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2a_n}{3^{n+1}}$

where $a_n$ is drawn from $\{0,1\}$

If instead we take the set :

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{3a_n}{4^{n+1}}$

Then from the definitions I've read, being generated by $2^\omega$ I see no reason why this would not be a Cantor space.

I'm not clear what numbers it contains.  These seem to be numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ again, but those which can be written in base $4$, using only $0$s and $3$s.

Is this built by repeatedly removing the centre halves of every segment?

Then finally what I'm really interested in is the set:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{4^{n+1}}$

which I think is the same set as the last, this time divided throughout by $3$ so scaled down to the interval $[0,\frac13]$

Is it correct that is still a Cantor space, and what numbers does it contain?  It seems to be the numbers written in base $4$ using only $1$s and $0$s and is the interval $[0,\frac13]$ with the centre halves of every interval removed.

Comment: Most of what you wrote is correct, but "terminating in a 3" should be "with all digits equal to 0 or 3".

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank-you. I've corrected that. Is the "repeatedly removing the centre half" part correct?

Comment: Yes, "repeatedly removing the centre half" is correct. At the first step, the centre half you're removing contains all the points in which $\frac 14$ has coefficient 1 or 2; at the next step, the two centre halve you're removing contain the points in which \frac1{16} has coefficient 1 or 2; etc.